# Grunt watch doesn't work during grunt server task

Tags: gruntjs, livereload, grunt-contrib-watch

I am using Grunt with a grunt server task that performs a **watch task**. Unfortunately, after saving a less or coffee file, the "default" task that should be triggered by the watch taks doesn't get triggered and so the browser doesn't livereload.

I was searching the problem but didn't find a proper solution.

Here is an extract of my **Gruntfile.coffee**:

```
grunt.registerTask "server", [
    'less'
    'coffee'
    'copy'
    "concurrent:server"
    "connect:livereload"
    "open"
    "watch"
]

grunt.registerTask "default", [
    'less'
    'coffee'
    'copy'
]

watch:
    coffee:
        files: [
            '<%= assets %>/scripts/{,*/}*.coffee'
            'Gruntfile.coffee'
            '<%= assets %>/scripts/*.coffee'
        ]

    less:
        files: [
            '<%= assets %>/styles/**/**/*.less'
            '<%= assets %>/styles/**/*.less'
            '<%= assets %>/styles/*.less'
            ]

    files: [
        'app/**/*.php'
        'app/**/*.html'
    ]

    tasks: 'default'

    livereload:
        options:
            livereload: LIVERELOAD_PORT # is 37562

        files: [
            "<%= assets %>/{,*/}*.html"
            '<%= assets %>/styles/**/*.less'
            '<%= assets %>/scripts/*.coffee'
            '<%= assets %>/styles/**/*.less'
            '<%= assets %>/styles/*.less'
        ]
```

Thank you for your help in advance! :)

Answer (score 2):

Why not define separate tasks for each of your watched file groups?

```
watch:
  coffee:
    files: [
      'Gruntfile.coffee'
      '<%= assets %>/scripts/*.coffee'
    ]
    tasks: 'coffee'

  less:
    files: [
      '<%= assets %>/styles/**/**/*.less'
      '<%= assets %>/styles/**/*.less'
      '<%= assets %>/styles/*.less'
    ]
    tasks: 'less
```

This will compile your CoffeeScript when a `.coffee` file is saved, and compile your less when a `.less` file is saved. It doesn't make sense to recompile all your `less` files when a `coffee` file is changed, and vice versa.

Answer (score 2):

You're watch task is incorrectly configured. It takes blocks of `files` to watch and `tasks` to run. Both your `coffee` and `less` targets are configured to watch files but not run tasks. Then you have a block that is not within any target.

Take a closer look at the examples on the watch task: https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-watch#examples

Here is a (semi) fixed config:

```
watch:
  coffee:
    files: [
      '<%= assets %>/scripts/{,*/}*.coffee'
      'Gruntfile.coffee'
      '<%= assets %>/scripts/*.coffee'
    ]
    tasks: ['coffee']

  less:
    files: [
      '<%= assets %>/styles/**/**/*.less'
      '<%= assets %>/styles/**/*.less'
      '<%= assets %>/styles/*.less'
    ]
    tasks: ['less']

   TARGETNAMENEEDEDHERE:
     files: [
       'app/**/*.php'
       'app/**/*.html'
     ]
     tasks: 'default'

   ###
   The files in this target are not configured correctly.
   Typically people create a livereload target to watch destination files.
   So the livereload will only trigger when one of the above targets writes
   to a destination file. But you're watching source files below.
   ###
   livereload:
      options:
        livereload: LIVERELOAD_PORT # is 37562
      files: [
        "<%= assets %>/{,*/}*.html"
        '<%= assets %>/styles/**/*.less'
        '<%= assets %>/scripts/*.coffee'
        '<%= assets %>/styles/**/*.less'
        '<%= assets %>/styles/*.less'
      ]
```